# Vertex sizes scaled by vertex degree?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Is there any way of scaling the sizes of the vertices of a network proportional to the vertex-degrees of the vertices in Mathematica?
Thanks.

Comment: I believe there is a topic about that here but I can't find it. Meanwhile a community topic: [On design of styles for small weighted graphs](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/838652?p_p_auth=oq8hU3PR)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[5]
g = RandomGraph[{6, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
vd = Thread[VertexList@g -> Normalize[VertexDegree@g, Total]];
g2 = SetProperty[g, VertexSize -> vd]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Great! Why are you dividing by 20 here?

Comment: @dbm,  dividing by 20 was to scale the vertex sizes. It is removed in the updated post.

Comment: Got it. However, this code doesn't work for say 
g = RandomGraph[{90, 120}]

Comment: @dbm, maybe you can use `Normalize[VertexDegree@g, Max]` for large graphs.

Comment: No I mean when you draw the larger network with your code, it doesn't show any nodes at all. I guess you just need to multiply Normalize by 100 or something, otherwise the node size would be scaled too small to see.

Comment: @dbm, it is because  when we normalize by `Total` each vertex degree divided by `Total[VertexDegree@g]` (240) gives a very small vertex size. If we normalize by `Max` each vertex degree is divided by `7` (maximum of the vertex degrees). Alternatively, instead of `Normalize[...]`, you can use `Rescale[VertexDegree@g, Through[{Min, Max}[VertexDegree@g]], {a, b}]`  with your choice of `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 2):

This code scales the vertex size and attaches a heatmap color to the vertices.  The result is as follows:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
(* Define some utility functions *)
addVertices[G_, numVertices_] := (
  GN = G;
  vc = VertexCount[GN];
  (* Preferential Attachment Part A *)
  For[i = 1, i <= numVertices, i++,
   (* Preferential Attachment Part A Barabasi / Albert Method *)
   (* The rich get richer... *)
   GN = EdgeAdd[
     GN, (vc + i) \[UndirectedEdge] RandomChoice[GraphCenter[GN]]];
   (* Preferential Attachment Experiment 1 *)
   GN = EdgeAdd[
     GN, (vc + i) \[UndirectedEdge] RandomChoice[GraphPriphery[GN]]];
   ];
  Return[Graph[GN, VertexLabels -> Automatic, 
    PlotLabel -> "New G with additional vertices"]]
  )
If[$KernelCount < 1, LaunchKernels[]];
Framed[Style[
  StringJoin["Running [", ToString[$KernelCount], "] kernels"]], 
 Background -> LightBlue]
numNodes = 900;
m = 3; (* Parameter of attachment *)
G = Graph[RandomGraph[BarabasiAlbertGraphDistribution[numNodes, m]], 
  VertexStyle -> White];
vcount = VertexCount[G];
heatIndex = Table[VertexDegree[G, i], {i, 1, vcount}] ;
Length[Range[Max[heatIndex]]];
tempRange = Table[ColorData["TemperatureMap"][r], {r, 0., 1., 1/%}];
tempDegree = Table[tempRange[[heatIndex[[i]]]], {i, 1, vcount}];
vs = Table[i -> tempDegree[[i]], {i, 1, vcount}];
vh = Table[
   i -> (Log[numNodes]*m*heatIndex[[i]])/(Max[heatIndex]), {i, 1, 
    vcount}];
pl = Style[
   StringJoin[
    "Heat/Size Map of Random Barabasi/Albert Graph\nO(V) = ", 
    ToString[numNodes], ", Diameter G = ", ToString[GraphDiameter[G]],
     ", m = ", ToString[m]], Bold, FontFamily -> "Comic Sans MS"];
G = Graph[G, VertexStyle -> vs, VertexSize -> vh, PlotLabel -> pl]
```

[image]

Comment: There are still some scaling issues in the above graph.  We are trying to scale based on two different variables, O(V) and the parameter m, i.e. the parameter of attachment.  I notice in the first answer a normalization was used but I used a Log of the number of nodes.  There is something strange, though with Mathematica, in that if you change O(V) to 1000 the vertices all resort to the same size???

Comment: Neither of the above proposed solutions scale properly when the number of nodes goes over 1000.  Its as if something changes with Wolfram's scaling.